# Php File-uploading doesn't work properly

Tags: php, file-upload

I manage to download the image to C:\wamp\www\images\ . However the file's first letter  is deleted. I don't know why this is happening. Also, I can't display the image on the webpage. Can you help me out,please?

This php file displays the info about file and also suppose to display image but it doesn't.

```
<html><head><title>File Uploads</title></head>
<body bgcolor="#33ff33">
<font face="verdana" size="+1">
<?php
   echo "The uploaded file is: ", $_FILES['picture_file']['tmp_name'], "<br />";
   $filename=$_FILES['picture_file']['name'];
   $filesize=$_FILES['picture_file']['size'];
   echo "filename".$filename;
   $directory='C:\wamp\www\images\\';
   $uploadFile = $directory . $filename;
   echo "The moved file is: $uploadFile<br />";
   if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['picture_file']['tmp_name'],
   $uploadFile)){
   echo "The file is valid and was successfully uploaded.
   <br /> ";
   echo "The image file, $filename, is $filesize bytes.<br 
   />";
}

?>

<br/>

 <img src=<?php
    echo "\"c:\wamp\www\images\\$filename\""?>>

</font>
</body>
</html>
```

This html form to upload image

```
<html><head><title>Uploading Pictures</title></head>
<body bgcolor="lavender">
<h3>Uploading Files</h3>
<form
 enctype="multipart/form-data"
 action="upload_move_file.php"
 method="post">
 Browse and select the picture you want to upload: <br />
<input name="picture_file" type="file" />
<br />
<input type=submit value="Get File"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: don't know about your first letter being removed, but the img src is wrong, read a bit on google or somewhere about the webservice's home directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If "www" is your Document Root than the image source would be "/images/$filename".

Comment: Thanks it displays the image now but still eating the first letter.

Comment: What is the name of the file? Maybe its an invalid character or something. Good practice is to change the filename on upload anyways to prevent hackers from injecting possibly harmful code to your server. You will also want to verify that the file being uploaded is indeed an image. I usually just verify the file extention.

Comment: No, the first letter is not an invalid character. I tried with other files, but same thing happens. Thank you for the advices, anyway.